# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused

Tags: curl, nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

Need help. Have been trying for a solution to this issue and could not see an answer or rather I have not come across any.

I have a docker container with NGINX, acting as a reverse proxy. Docker for Windows version 1.12.5(9503).

```
upstream mysite {
    server 127.0.0.1:8090;
    #server localhost:8090; (have also tried this option)
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysite;
    }
}
```

In the above code localhost:8090 is a url of a website that is hosted on IIS on my host machine. When I access the url on NGINX, I get the following error

```
2016/12/27 08:11:57 [error] 6#6: *4 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://googlesite/", host: "localhost"
172.17.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2016:08:11:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0" "-"
```

---

Tried to access the url on the host machine

> ***(simple HTML site, single page with only simple html, hosted on IIS with anonymous access granted to all.)***

```
curl localhost:8090
```

Getting the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused
```

Am new to Docker and NGINX. Would like to know if it is possible to access urls on the host machine? If Yes, then where am I wrong.

The same configuration works, if I use google.co.in instead of 127.0.0.1:8090.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inside a docker container the `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` refer to the container itself. In order to access the host machine running dockerd with your container you must refer to the host by its public hostname/IP as if it was another machine on the network.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Instead of using localhost, i used the hostname and it worked wonderful. Modified conf details below:

'upstream mysite { server hostname:8090; }'

'server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysite;
    }
}'

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I've tried using 0.0.0.0 in place of hostname also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976913/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-an-app-in-host.

Comment: I was facing similar issue without docker in nginx and this fixed me. Thank you.