# error : curl: (52) Empty reply from server , when ingesting data into druid

Tags: docker, druid

I found this : [curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363529/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-8090-connection-refused/42598270?noredirect=1#comment72327566_42598270) . But, not able to resolve the issue.

I tried using the public ip of my machine but then it gave me another error : "curl: (52) Empty reply from server" .

I also tried 0.0.0.0 as it was mentioned in some other posts. But same issue. Do i need to do something else ?

here is the command I execute to run my docker image : "docker run -t -p 8000:8000 -p 8090:8090 $IMAGE_ID"

and this is the command I use to ingest batch data into druid :

"curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @./../druid/stb_ad_trait/index.json $MY_MACHINE_IP:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task" .

Any idea please ?

Comment: When you ssh to the docker container can you curl the status endpoint ? like curl localhost:8090/status ? That will tell you if the druid process is up. Then if it is up and running your issue might be Docker configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the official dockerised image the Coordinator works as both the Coordinator and the Overlord.
See for a reference: 
https://github.com/druid-io/docker-druid/blob/master/supervisord.conf#L30

Perhaps that is the case with your setup as well? If so, simply use the Coordinator port (`8081`) instead of the Overlord port (`8090`).

http://host:8081/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor