# Nginx reverse proxy to an app in host

Tags: docker, nginx, go, webserver, reverse-proxy

I have an app that is running outside Docker on port 5000. I am trying to run a reverse proxy in nginx via Docker compose but am unable to communicate with the host's port 5000. In my docker-compose.yml file I have:

```
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
  - 5000:5000
```

When I try to run this I get:

```
ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx (374026a0d34c8b6b789dcd82d6aee6c4684b3201258cfbd3fb18623c4101): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use
```

If I comment out `- 5000:5000` I get:

```
[error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

How do I connect to an already running app in the Host from a Docker nginx container?

EDIT:

My nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    upstream mysite {
        server 0.0.0.0:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysite;
        }
    }
}
```

The response when I try to curl localhost is `502 Bad Gateway`. The app itself and curl 127.0.0.1:5000 responds fine from the host.

EDIT 2:
I have also tried the [solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363529/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-8090-connection-refused) but I get `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "docker"`. Docker is my host's hostname.

EDIT 3:
My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  simple:
    build: ./simple
    container_name: simple
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

EDIT:

I am getting the computer host via the "hostname" command in linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lies with 0.0.0.0:5000. Since Nginx is running inside the docker, it tries to find this address inside docker machine but fails since there is nothing running on 0.0.0.0:5000 inside docker.

So in order to resolve this

1. You need to give it an address that it can reach. Solving it requires that you 
   first run your application at 0.0.0.0:5000 on your host machine i.e you should be able to open your application at 0.0.0.0:5000 from your browser.
2. **Find your IP address.** once you get your IP address you should be able to 
    open you application through ***ip_address:5000.*** since your docker and  host share the same network this address can be reached from docker also
3. Now, replace the **0.0.0.0:5000** in your Nginx conf file with this **ip_address:5000**. you would be able to serve your application

Answer (score 5):

**172.17.0.1** is the default host ip available to docker container running on host.
Just use **172.17.0.1:5000** in your nginx conf file and you should be able to connect to your application running on host outside the container.
My docker version is **19.03.12** where I tested the same.

Answer (score 1):

I need to use a different variable to access the host container: `http://host.docker.internal`.